# re-apply css classes using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have many divs on a page that the height and width are altered based on the user.  Is there an easy way to restore the styles back to the default value in the css page itself without actually refreshing the page.

I know I could manually apply the height and width back to the default, but didn't know if there was a way to have jquery apply the class values back to the element that's been modified?

Thanks for any help

Comment: How are you altering the height and width for the specific user?

Comment: ... under what conditions do you need that to happen? ... you can do that if you can specify the event to trigger the reset.

Comment: I'm using the css function.  Some panel are larger thanothers depending on the user and their role.  I just needed a quick way to reapply the css classes similar to the way the page is first loaded without actually reloading the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out 'addClass' and 'removeClass':

```
$('.the_div').removeClass('defaultStyle').addClass('defaultStyle');
```

That will reset the style to the defaultStyle class. You could also just set `attr('class', 'defaultStyle')`, but this will also remove any other classes you have on the same div.

Answer (score 6):

if you are only having width and height modified try

```
$('.mydivclass').css({width: '', height: ''})
```

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed this would work, but it does! Beats tracking original values in a variable or some such.

Comment: Makes sense, but I just didn't know/make the connection. I will add this to my toolkit. Cheers!

Comment: you're welcome, it's a bit un-intuitive as to me, setting them to null would make more sense

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea how you're persisting the changes but if you are using the style attribute to keep the changes you can do something like this

```
$('div').removeAttr('style');
```